# How to get spring post param in a form with any name

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

I want to get parameter from POST method in Spring with name that starts with "value". And it can be like "value_345465". Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Spring Controllers?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing Spring MVC specific. You can use [`ServletRequest.getParameterNames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames--), [`ServletRequest.getParameterMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap--), and [`ServletRequest.getParameter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-) methods to accomplish this task.